# Need to find the first and last rows from a mysql table recursively and display them in a pair format

Tags: mysql

Say for example,I have a table with data :

Order by Some weight desc ,Rank asc :

```
ID  : Weight : Rank desc
8   : 7      : 2
7   : 7      : 3
4   : 5      : 2
6   : 4      : 1
2   : 2      : 4
9   : 2      : 2
```

I need to display pair of data from first and last rows recursively from this list.
Rows may be odd or even and is not fixed.It may be 100s.

Result returned should be like :

```
ID : (8,9)**(7,2)**(4,6)
```

I am thinking of Mysql Select UNION but not getting it properly.Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this // the idea is you'll be pairing sorted table with invert sorted table:

```
SET @fw=0; #forwards counter/index
SET @bw=(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM yourtable); #backwards index
SET @limit= @bw/2; #limit tohalf the set to avoid full set of versions (resulting in duplicates)


SELECT a.id, b.id
FROM (
SELECT @bw:=@bw-1 AS ct, id
FROM `yourtable` 
ORDER BY id
) a, (
SELECT @fw:=@fw+1 AS ct, id
FROM `yourtable` 
ORDER BY id
) b 
WHERE a.ct = b.ct
AND a.ct <= @limit
```

Comment: As per your provided answer will this be the query as per table above :                                                                                                                                      
SELECT a.id, b.id
FROM (
SELECT 9:=9-1 AS ct, id
FROM `my_single_table` 
ORDER BY id
) a, (
SELECT 0:=0+1 AS ct, id
FROM `my_single_table` 
ORDER BY id
) b 
WHERE a.ct = b.ct
AND a.ct <= 3
                                                             Will this query work in Mysql or its invalid.I have also first to list rows by weight desc and rank asc,where shall I place in this query above?

Comment: The `fw` and `bw` and `limit` are variables - they would fit ANY size table, you don't need to change them to fixed (the edit you provided would not work i think). The given one is a valid MySQL query. If you need to list the rows first, then it is a derivate table, and you should use it like `... FROM (SELECT ID, Weight, Rank FROM someOtherTable ... ) x`

Comment: additional explanation: If you need to list the rows first, then it is a derivate table, and you should use it like `... FROM (SELECT ID, Weight, Rank FROM someOtherTable ... ) yourtable` instead of `FROM yourtable`

Comment: I got it.First I need to list the data in by weight desc and rank asc from the `yourtable` and save it in a temporary table,from that temporaray table I run your mysql queries,fetch the pairs and then delete the old rows from the temporary table : 'temp_table' .so in your query,`yourtable` would be replaced by this 'temp_table'.
Let me fill some junk data and test it.Thanks anyways for the time and solution.

Comment: for 6 row IDs,auto incremented in above sample table format,I got results :

(5,1)**(4,2)**(3,3)

Not getting ID : 6 ,i.e (1,6) ** (2,5) ** (3,4)
Atleast I got some start.Thanks but just this one issue remains.Pls help.

Comment: @fw=-1;

(6,1)**(5,2)**(4,3)**(3,4)

@fw=1;
(4,1)**(3 ,2)

what to do?

Comment: Best way ..if odd exclude the last row,make it even rows,then from these returned even rows based pairs,exclude the last result pair.That's the final result which I think would solve all doubts..

Comment: You can adjust the select scope by editing the @limit variable, if it is even it is @bw/2 if odd (@bw % 2 = 1) it's (@bw-1)/2.